# App not opening after tapping on notification react native firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have integrated react native firebase to my app and I want to send notifications to my app from firebase cloud messaging, when I send notifications from firebase console then the notification works well but when I send the notification from the server the notification comes up after I tap on the notification, it doesnot open the app.

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep links in react-native-firebase notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150199/deep-links-in-react-native-firebase-notifications)

Comment: Bro. Did you fixed it? coz im having the same issue.

Comment: Yes I fixed , I just removed the data payload from the backend

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Listener for this.
Look at this Posting to get an Idea, how you can implement it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53227998/1256697

Comment: Hello, Can you check this question please @suther https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171787/navigate-to-screen-after-opening-a-notification